# How do I add a link to this button?

Tags: button, images, hyperlink, salesforce-cms, link

I've created a banner image with a text and a button using CMS, but I couldn't find a way to add a link to the button. Open to any suggestions, thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This has to be done in Content Management.

**Steps:**

1. Click on workspaceIconContainer icon in the top left corner
2. Now select the Content Management option
3. Now go to your Promo Banner, update the **Button URL**, and save and publish the content.

Refresh your page!
And you can see it working.